# Thread in for-loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

How do I know if a thread is finished when I create it in a loop?
Simplified code:

```
Public Sub LoadExcelFiles()
AddMore: 
        Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf CreateExcelFile))
        t.Start()

'Check if there are more files.
'If yes: GoTo AddMore
End Sub
```

How do I know when thread 't' is completed? I want to add the file created by 't' into a treeview.
Another problem is, when the user drops 33 files, I have 11 threads running at the same time (3 excelfiles are used per thread)

Comment: Use parallel.For() and learn to write loops without GoTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting article about the answer of @Paul Deen (wish is a good solution) can be found at http://tech.xster.net/tips/multi-threading-in-vb-net/

Tho I did it another way.

```
    Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf CreateExcelFile))
    If t.IsAlive Then
        t.Join()
    Else
        t.Start()
    End If

'Some code here

    While t.IsAlive
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep("500")
    End While

    MessageBox.Show("All Files Completed")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider doing it like this:

```
Delegate Sub CreateExcelFileAsync()
Public Sub LoadExcelFiles()
        Dim d As New CreateExcelFileAsync(AddressOf CreateExcelFile)

        Dim result As IAsyncResult = d.BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)

        '..
        'more work
        '..
        'wait until completed before starting over

        If Not result.IsCompleted() Then
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()
        End If

        d.EndInvoke(result)
End Sub
```

This way you can use the AsyncResult to check the completion.

Comment: How can I access it when it reaches the 'End Sub'.
Because when the threads are all started it ends that sub.

Comment: It would still be available to you when you reach end sub.  I presumed when there were files, you started processing them in another thread, while your application continued to do other work.  After that, you check if there's more files to be done, immediately after thread has completed, to start the cycle.  Sort of the async/await model.